How can I make sure that my manifest.json is fetched in a Progressive Web App (PWA)?
I am building a simple Progressive Web App. I pushed my app to a subfolder on my website, and when I ran the Lighthouse audit in Chrome it failed the PWA audit because "Web app manifest or service worker do not meet the installability requirements." When I looked for more details, it gave the failure reason as "Manifest could not be fetched, is empty, or could not be parsed." Visiting the page on Chrome for Android does not give an option to install the page as a PWA (just to save a shortcut).
I have a manifest.json and a service worker, however I'm not very experienced with troubleshooting. I basically followed this tutorial for the structure and naming conventions, but added some additional buttons and functions to the index.html page. My manifest.json, in the main folder, looks like this (I cut the icons portion for space, I have an images subfolder with all the icons in the right size, and they are linked with relative paths in that part of the json):
{
"name": "Web app name",
"short_name": "app name",
"icons": [{
    .... 
}],
"lang": "en-US",
"start_url": "/index.html",
"display": "standalone",
"background_color": "white",
"theme_color": "white",
"prefer_related_applications": "false"
}

I added "prefer_related_applications": "false" after reading one of the chrome developer pages, but that didn't seem to fix anything. This manifest.json is linked in the head of index.html:
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

My service worker looks like:
var cacheName = 'hello-pwa';
var filesToCache = [
  '/',
  '/index.html',
  '/css/style.css',
  '/js/main.js',
  '/manifest.json'
];

/* Start the service worker and cache all of the app's content */
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});

/* Serve cached content when offline */
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});

I added manifest.json to the cache, thinking that might be the issue. But it still did not pass the audit. The service worker is in a script tag at the bottom of the index.html page:
<script src = "js/sw.js"></script>

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could improve this code so that this becomes an installable PWA? The tutorial notes that the service worker script might not be suitable for production, so I expected something like this might happen. But I can't figure out what is making the service worker or manifest unsuitable.
